# Unique identifier in loop how to

Tags: php, loops, foreach, identifier

I am trying to apply a unique identifier to each item in my loop.  below is the sample from my loop and I am using it to show the fancybox lightbox.

```
<?php function my_feed() {

          $feed = fetch_feed( 'http://somewhere.com/feed' );
      if ( ! is_wp_error( $feed) ):

      // Get a maximum of 5 items

      $maxitems = $feed->get_item_quantity( 5 );

      $items = $feed->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

      foreach ( $items as $item ):

      ?>

      <div id="listing" class="twelve columns">


          <div class="four columns">

                <img src="#" height="200" width="200" /> <br/>

          </div>

          <div class="eight columns border">


              <!-- need this to be #more-info1. #more-info2, and so on -->
              <a href="#more-info" class="fancybox"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a>


              <span class="rss-date"><?php echo $item->get_date( 'F j, Y' ); ?></span>

          </div>

      </div>

      <!-- this will coincide with the anchor so the id should be more-info1, more-info2, and so on -->
      <div id="more-info" style="display:none;width:auto;">
          <h3><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></h3>
          <p>

              <?php echo $item->get_date( 'F j, Y' ); ?>

          </p>
          <p>
           <?php echo $item->get_description(); ?>
           <?php echo '<a href="'. $item->get_permalink().'>Link Here</a>'; ?>
           </p>
      </div>

      <?php

      endforeach;

      else: // Returned WP_Error, unable to fetch the feed. ?>

      <p>There was an error</p>

      <?php endif; ?>


      <?php
      }  ?>
```

So when I am looking to have a unique number after "#more-info" the href in the anchor tag like "#more-info1" and "#more-info2" and so on for the anchor tag.  Then it will have a matching div with an id of "more-info1" and "more-info2" and so on.  I know that it should run something like $myvariable++ but honestly I cant get it to work and have no idea on what to do.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ( $items as $item ):
?>
<a href="#more-info<?php echo $i++; ?>" class="fancybox">
<?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: That made things go haywire, I pretty much added the i variable right before the anchor tag with the for each and ended the foreach after the div with id of "more-info" not sure if it is because I am running a foreach within another foreach or because I already have a $items as $item defined in the first foreach..  Sorry im relatively new to this

Comment: could you post your current code somewhere? $i variable should be set before foreach starts.. Then, for every item, you need to increase $i by 1 and echo it anywhere you want.

Comment: Sure, i did define the variable before the for each though.  Code can be seen at http://www.pastebin.com/BmSY5DDX

Comment: Got it, so the problem was that I was running a foreach inside of another foreach.  I fixed it by removing the second foreach and defining the i variable before the foreach and then adding the $i++ after the foreach and of course echoing my variable $i in my anchor and div tags.  Thanks so much for your help!!